# Fusing odom, imu, magnetometer with robot localization

Tags: imu, navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm looking for information about fusing odometry with imu and magnetometer. Just in 2D.
My sensors are connected to an embbeded systems and I'm publishing raw data to ROS using rosserial.
Right now I'm publishing odometry, IMU (raw Gyro and accel data) and raw (after calibration) magnetometer data. I'm not providing orientation data, just raw data.
What is better, fusing all raw data in robot_localization? make some complimentary filter between gyro and magnetometer and publish orientation in IMU msg? has someone a config file for robot_localization with this sensors?
I'm not sure what magneticfield data could be added to RL config file. I think I need to, at least, calculate heading with magnetometer an publish it...

thank

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348679/fusing-odom,-imu,-magnetometer-with-robot-localization/) by [elgarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/32969/elgarbe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2020-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it were me, I'd feed the IMU and magnetometer data to [imu_filter_madwick](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_filter_madgwick). Then I'd fuse the output of that node with the wheel odometry data in an `r_l` EKF instance. That's a pretty straightforward setup, and the EKF [config example](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/799ad4481b8b16b12a50c34725dbbe4d82b4a84a/params/ekf_template.yaml) would be a good place to start.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2020-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elgarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/32969/elgarbe/) on 2020-05-05**:
Thank you very much Tom for you time. I will do that.

**Comment by [p_user2001](https://answers.ros.org/users/83138/p_user2001/) on 2021-08-31**:
Hi Tom, Could you kindly let me know what an r_l EKF instance is? Thank you

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2021-09-06**:
`r_l` = `robot_localization`
EKF instance = Extended Kalman Filter node instance. As in, an instance of the `ekf_localization_node`.